# Mirage rake tasks fail when mirage is not runnning

Tags: ruby, cygwin, rake, windows-7-x64

Good day,

I have a simply Rake file:

```
require 'mirage/client'

namespace :mock_server do
  desc "Checks to see if the mock server is currently running"
  task :running? do
    puts Mirage::Client.new.running? ? 'Yep' : 'Nope'
  end
end
```

If Mirage is running this works fine, however if Mirage is not it fails with:

```
$ rake --trace -f test.rb.txt mock_server:running?
** Invoke mock_server:running? (first_time)
** Execute mock_server:running?
rake aborted!
Operation not permitted - connect(2)
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:560:in `initialize'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:560:in `open'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:560:in `connect'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:53:in `timeout'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:93:in `timeout'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:560:in `connect'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:553:in `do_start'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:542:in `start'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:1035:in `request'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mirage-2.0.16/lib/mirage/client/web.rb:36:in `http_get'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mirage-2.0.16/lib/mirage/client.rb:135:in `running?'
/cygdrive/c/Code/SocialMedia/tests/features/test.rb.txt:6
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `execute'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `top_level'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `top_level'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33
/usr/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/usr/bin/rake:19
Tasks: TOP => mock_server:running?
```

I'm running ruby 1.8.7 installed using the Cygwin installer, mirage 2.0.16 via gem on Windows 7.  Do you know of any reason why this is failing?

Cheers,
    Mlk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be the version of Ruby. Tried with Ruby 1.9 and all is good with the world.